# Undefined pop-up when refreshing sugarcrm dashlet

Tags: admin, sugarcrm

I'm trying to modify a Sugarcrm (version 6.5.4).I'm logged as "Administrator"

I have a homepage, where i deleted some useless dashlets. Every dashlet on this home is refreshing every 30 seconds.
And every 30 seconds, i have a little pop-up appearing just few miliseconds saying just "Undefined". I tried to see with firebug what could be the error, and i did not find out.
I think maybe i deleted a field or something in my other datas which is related with a dashlet, but i can't see which one.

Does anybody have an idea on which error is running? or even if i can fix it, please?

Thanks for the time you took to read my poor description.
and Thanks by advance for the response you'll give me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i didn't find what was the cause of this popup, but i had several problems with the acces rights. 
I changed them and now the popup turned from "Undefined" to "Loading".
Thanks again, and i hope it will help someone! :)